# Google map Activity(Not getting lat,lang)

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

Here I'm trying to get the current location on the google maps activity. but it is no fetching the latitude or longitude when the map page is loaded. Assist me here. while checking with the breakpoints, latitude, and longitude values are null.

```
private void configureCameraIdle() {
    onCameraIdleListener = new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {

            LatLng latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(TrialActivity.this);

            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                    String locality = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    String country = addressList.get(0).getCountryName();

                    System.out.println("Address             "+addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                    System.out.println("getAdminArea         "+addressList.get(0).getAdminArea());
                    System.out.println("getCountryCode       "+addressList.get(0).getCountryCode());
                    System.out.println("getCountryName       "+addressList.get(0).getCountryName());
                    System.out.println("getExtras           "+addressList.get(0).getExtras());
                    System.out.println("getLocale           "+addressList.get(0).getLocale());
                    System.out.println("getLocality         "+addressList.get(0).getLocality());
                    System.out.println("getPhone            "+addressList.get(0).getPhone());
                    System.out.println("getPostalCode        "+addressList.get(0).getPostalCode());
                    System.out.println("getPremises          "+addressList.get(0).getPremises());
                    System.out.println("getSubAdminArea      "+addressList.get(0).getSubAdminArea());
                    System.out.println("getSubLocality       "+addressList.get(0).getSubLocality());

                             if (locality!=null && country!=null)
                            {
                                if (!locality.isEmpty() && !country.isEmpty())
                                    resutText.setQuery(locality + "  " + country,true);
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Please drag map to valid address..");
                            }

                        }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I don't know this call .getCameraPosition() but if you need your current location you should consider requesting it from the android OS -> https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates

Comment: @Emanuel will look into it.